# Precomputing Client-side Javascript Execution

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs

Suppose you were to build a highly functional single-page client-side application that listens to URL changes in order to navigate around the application.

Suppose then, that when a user (or search engine bot) loads a page by its url, instead of delivering the static javascript file and hits the api as normal, we'd like to precompute everything server-side and delivery the DOM along with the js state.

I am wondering if there are existing tools or techniques for persisting such an execution of state to the client.

I know that I could execute the script in something like phantom JS and output the DOM elements, but then event handlers, controllers and the js memory state would not be attached properly. I could sniff our user agent and only send the precomputed content to bots, but I am afraid google would punish for this, and we also lose the speed benefits of having sent everything precomputed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to compile, server-side and send to the client the results of requesting a resource at a specific URL?  What is your backend written in?

We have an API running on GAE in Java.  Our app is a single-page app, and we use the HTML5 history object so we have to have "real responses" for actual URLs on the front-end.

To handle this we use JSP to pre-cache the data in the page as it's loaded from the server and sent to the client.

On the front end we use Backbone, so we modified `Backbone.sync` to look for a copy of the data it's looking for locally on the page and if it's not there, only then to request it from the server as an AJAX call.

So, yes, this is pretty much what every site did before you had ajax.  The trick is writing your app so that the data can be local in the page (or in localStorage even) and if not only then to request the data.  Then make sure your page is "built" on the server end (so we actually populate the data in the HTML elements on the server end so the page doesn't require JS on the client end).

If you go somewhere else the data is dynamic and the page doesn't reload.